# Java inheritance and method overloading

Tags: java, inheritance, overloading, overriding

I've tried to execute the following code:

```
abstract class A {
    int met(A a) { return 0;}
    int met(B b) { return 1;}
    int met(C c) { return 2;}
}
class B extends A {
    int met(A a) { return 3;}
    int met(B b) { return 4;}
    int met(C c) { return 5;}
}
class C extends B {
    int fun() {
        return ((A) this).met((A) this);
    }
}
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C x = new C();
        System.out.println(x.fun());
    }
}
```

And the output is "3".

Can someone explain in more detail the theoretical concept behind this result.

I know that class A is abstract and that's why it cannot be instantiated but I'd like to understand the whole mechanism of this result.

Answer (score 6):

The overloaded method is selected at compile time. Since your code calls `met((A) this)`, the method signature with the argument of type `A` is chosen.

Now, at run time, the JVM has to decide which `met(A a)` method to execute. This is determined by the runtime type of the object for which the method is called. Since your object is of type C which extends B, `met(A a)` of `B` (which overrides `met(A a)` of `A`) is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Method signatures are determined at compile time.

```
.met(A)
```

must be called as the signature doesn't change based on the actual type of the object, only the type is appears to be.

However, polymorphism does apply to determine which implementation of this signature is called.

The object `this` is a `C` which extends `B` and so the implementation in `B` is the one called.

This is why `B.met(A)` is called.

Answer (score 1):

B is the only class implementing A so A implementations will never be executed as B as overrided them.

When you cast your C object as A, it's still a C object so calling met on this object will execute the method of B. This call is resolved at runtime using the real type of the object.

Concerning the parameter, you casted it as a A so the java compiler made it point to the right method : B.met(A)

Answer (score 1):

```
return ((A) this).met((A) this);
```

When you write `this` it's always points to current instance which is `C` which extends `B`, and you didn't over-ridden the method hence it's pointing to the method of super class (`B`).

And coming to the part `(A) this`, it still points to `this` only, not the `A`. The underlying implementation of methods still remains same. You are just changing type.

Answer (score 0):

**((A) this)**.met(**(A) this**)      interpreted  as 
 - **instanceOfC**.met(**typeOfA**)

so two questions arise, why is

- class selected as **B** not A - **subclass over super class**
- within class B met is selected as **met(A)** not met(C) or met(B) - **type over instance**

#### A. Overriding - subclass over super class

- if same method signature in the **object's** sub-class and super-class,
- then it was selected it from sub-class.
- so ((A) this).met resolver to **instanceOfC.met**

#### B. Overloading - type over instance

- if duplicate method name found in the class
- then selected was one with same parameter as the argument passed,
- hence met **((A) instanceOfC)** interpreted as met(**typeOfArgument**)

### so

- **this.met((A) null)** will also invoke B.met(A)
- **this.met(this)** will invoke **B.met(C)**
- if we remove B.met(C), **this.met(this)** will invoke **A.met(C)**, i.e. overriding doesnt happen.
- and then removing A.met(C), it will invoke **B.met(B)**, - overloading by closest **typecast-able** parameter.